# How do I create a link to Twitter login pop up/lightbox iframe for people to post tweets without using the standard tweet button?

Tags: jquery, iframe, twitter, time, loading

I'd like to create a link/lightbox to twitter for people to post about my site, but I don't want to use the standard tweet button supplied by twitter, as it adds 100k to my homepages loading time.

Basically I'm trying to keep the loading time down to boost google traffic to my site.

Is there any way of linking to twitter in the same way as the tweet button but with minimal impact to my site and maybe keep the customer on my site by using a lightbox.

---

I could use a lightbox (http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/) and link to the code generated by the tweet button

eg: https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?original_referer=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fdocs%2Ftweet-button&text=Tweet%20Button%20|%20Twitter%20Developers&tw_p=tweetbutton&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdev.twitter.com%2Fdocs%2Ftweet-button

but I'm not sure if this would create an error as there is in effect no tweet button being used

---

Thanks for your help

Judi

Answer (score 1):

I have discovered twitter doesn't seem to work with lightboxes as an iframe. Therefore as an alternative I have used a simple javascript popup, which does the same thing as the tweet button but is less intrusive on page loading times.

This link

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share/" onClick="return popup(this, 'notes')">my popup</a>
```

with this code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function popup(mylink, windowname)
{
if (! window.focus)return true;
var href;
if (typeof(mylink) == 'string')
   href=mylink;
else
   href=mylink.href;
window.open(href, windowname, 'width=550,height=420,scrollbars=yes');
return false;
}
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@brightmist.co.uk , your nice simple code is work to provide user to tweet anything.

How to auto-insert the @ourTwitterUsername inside the tweet box.

it's likely to be used so that user could tweet us directly without having to type @ourTwitterUsername into it?

or like auto-insert the title & the link/article that user's viewing ?